# Aligning items in Flexbox Nav bar

Tags: css

I am trying to use flexbox rather than floats for the navbar element of my web page, but for my layout at the desktop format I cannot get my title and list elements to be aligned at the far right and left of the nav bar.
From Googling It seems using `justify-content:space-between` should accomplish this, but they seem to be slightly inwards from the edge.

https://github.com/dustinbergsma6/techdegree-project-2

Comment: Insert your code here to the question.

Comment: Please upload an image of your nav-bar

Comment: Also add margin: 0 and padding: 0 to body if you didn't provided that because body has a default margin and padding of some pixels (don't remember the accurate value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `justify-content: space-between` declaration to `nav` element and add `justify-content: flex-end` declaration to `.nav-list` class

```css
/*! normalize.css v3.0.2 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */

/**
 * 1. Set default font family to sans-serif.
 * 2. Prevent iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling
 *    user zoom.
 */

html {
  font-family: sans-serif; /* 1 */
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove default margin.
 */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

/* HTML5 display definitions
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Correct `block` display not defined for any HTML5 element in IE 8/9.
 * Correct `block` display not defined for `details` or `summary` in IE 10/11
 * and Firefox.
 * Correct `block` display not defined for `main` in IE 11.
 */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
menu,
nav,
section,
summary {
  display: block;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct `inline-block` display not defined in IE 8/9.
 * 2. Normalize vertical alignment of `progress` in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.
 */

audio,
canvas,
progress,
video {
  display: inline-block; /* 1 */
  vertical-align: baseline; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Prevent modern browsers from displaying `audio` without controls.
 * Remove excess height in iOS 5 devices.
 */

audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
}

/**
 * Address `[hidden]` styling not present in IE 8/9/10.
 * Hide the `template` element in IE 8/9/11, Safari, and Firefox < 22.
 */

[hidden],
template {
  display: none;
}

/* Links
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the gray background color from active links in IE 10.
 */

a {
  background-color: transparent;
}

/**
 * Improve readability when focused and also mouse hovered in all browsers.
 */

a:active,
a:hover {
  outline: 0;
}

/* Text-level semantics
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 8/9/10/11, Safari, and Chrome.
 */

abbr[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

/**
 * Address style set to `bolder` in Firefox 4+, Safari, and Chrome.
 */

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in Safari and Chrome.
 */

dfn {
  font-style: italic;
}

/**
 * Address variable `h1` font-size and margin within `section` and `article`
 * contexts in Firefox 4+, Safari, and Chrome.
 */

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}

/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 8/9.
 */

mark {
  background: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}

/**
 * Address inconsistent and variable font size in all browsers.
 */

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

/**
 * Prevent `sub` and `sup` affecting `line-height` in all browsers.
 */

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

/* Embedded content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove border when inside `a` element in IE 8/9/10.
 */

img {
  border: 0;
}

/**
 * Correct overflow not hidden in IE 9/10/11.
 */

svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Grouping content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Address margin not present in IE 8/9 and Safari.
 */

figure {
  margin: 1em 40px;
}

/**
 * Address differences between Firefox and other browsers.
 */

hr {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
}

/**
 * Contain overflow in all browsers.
 */

pre {
  overflow: auto;
}

/**
 * Address odd `em`-unit font size rendering in all browsers.
 */

code,
kbd,
pre,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace;
  font-size: 1em;
}

/* Forms
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Known limitation: by default, Chrome and Safari on OS X allow very limited
 * styling of `select`, unless a `border` property is set.
 */

/**
 * 1. Correct color not being inherited.
 *    Known issue: affects color of disabled elements.
 * 2. Correct font properties not being inherited.
 * 3. Address margins set differently in Firefox 4+, Safari, and Chrome.
 */

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  color: inherit; /* 1 */
  font: inherit; /* 2 */
  margin: 0; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * Address `overflow` set to `hidden` in IE 8/9/10/11.
 */

button {
  overflow: visible;
}

/**
 * Address inconsistent `text-transform` inheritance for `button` and `select`.
 * All other form control elements do not inherit `text-transform` values.
 * Correct `button` style inheritance in Firefox, IE 8/9/10/11, and Opera.
 * Correct `select` style inheritance in Firefox.
 */

button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Avoid the WebKit bug in Android 4.0.* where (2) destroys native `audio`
 *    and `video` controls.
 * 2. Correct inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS.
 * 3. Improve usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type
 *    `input` and others.
 */

button,
html input[type="button"], /* 1 */
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button; /* 2 */
  cursor: pointer; /* 3 */
}

/**
 * Re-set default cursor for disabled elements.
 */

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and border in Firefox 4+.
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/**
 * Address Firefox 4+ setting `line-height` on `input` using `!important` in
 * the UA stylesheet.
 */

input {
  line-height: normal;
}

/**
 * It's recommended that you don't attempt to style these elements.
 * Firefox's implementation doesn't respect box-sizing, padding, or width.
 *
 * 1. Address box sizing set to `content-box` in IE 8/9/10.
 * 2. Remove excess padding in IE 8/9/10.
 */

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
  padding: 0; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Fix the cursor style for Chrome's increment/decrement buttons. For certain
 * `font-size` values of the `input`, it causes the cursor style of the
 * decrement button to change from `default` to `text`.
 */

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}

/**
 * 1. Address `appearance` set to `searchfield` in Safari and Chrome.
 * 2. Address `box-sizing` set to `border-box` in Safari and Chrome
 *    (include `-moz` to future-proof).
 */

input[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /* 2 */
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

/**
 * Remove inner padding and search cancel button in Safari and Chrome on OS X.
 * Safari (but not Chrome) clips the cancel button when the search input has
 * padding (and `textfield` appearance).
 */

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/**
 * Define consistent border, margin, and padding.
 */

fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct `color` not being inherited in IE 8/9/10/11.
 * 2. Remove padding so people aren't caught out if they zero out fieldsets.
 */

legend {
  border: 0; /* 1 */
  padding: 0; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove default vertical scrollbar in IE 8/9/10/11.
 */

textarea {
  overflow: auto;
}

/**
 * Don't inherit the `font-weight` (applied by a rule above).
 * NOTE: the default cannot safely be changed in Chrome and Safari on OS X.
 */

optgroup {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Tables
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove most spacing between table cells.
 */

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 0;
}

/* Lists
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove default list styles, margins and padding.
 */

ol,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

/*  Style.css */
body {
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 2.5em auto;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  font-family: Noto Sans;
}

#title {
  text-align: center;
}
.nav-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 1rem;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.nav-item {
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: white;
}

.nav-link {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.header {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.header img {
  width: 100%;
}

.header p {
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Portfolio Styles */
.portfolio {
  margin: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.portfolio h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.portfolio-image {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* Default Display Phone Size */

.portfolio-list {
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 1.25em;
}

.portfolio-item {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Media Query Tablet Size */

@media (min-width: 769px) {
  .portfolio-list {
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .portfolio-item {
    flex-basis: 47.5%;
  }

  .header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    position: relative;
  }

  .header p {
    margin: 0 15px;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .nav-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .nav-item {
    margin: 10px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
  }

  .nav-link {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }
}

/* Media Query Desktop Size  */

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .portfolio-list {
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .portfolio-item {
    flex-basis: 30%;
  }

  nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  #title {
    width: 40%;
    display: inline-flex;
  }
  .nav-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 1rem;
    /*width: 40%;
    float: right;*/
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }

  .nav-item {
    margin: 10px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    display: inline;
  }

  .nav-link {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <h1 id="title">Dustin Bergsma</h1>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#Home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#Portfolio" class="nav-link">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#Contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="header">
      <img src="images/responsive-layout-profile.png" />
      <p>
        Hi! I'm a front-end developer who loves responsive design and CSS. I
        recently finished learning front-end web development at Treehouse and am
        excited to put my skills to use!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio">
      <h2>PORTFOLIO</h2>
      <ul class="portfolio-list">
        <li class="portfolio-item">
          <img src="images/portfolio-1.png" alt="" class="portfolio-image" />
          <h4>Marketing Page</h4>
          <p>
            This project shows the front page of a marketing website meant for a
            specific business I'm interested in.
          </p>
        </li>
        <li class="portfolio-item">
          <img src="images/portfolio-2.png" alt="" class="portfolio-image" />
          <h4>Search Page</h4>
          <p>
            This project shows the front page of a marketing website meant for a
            specific business I'm interested in.
          </p>
        </li>
        <li class="portfolio-item">
          <img src="images/portfolio-3.png" alt="" class="portfolio-image" />
          <h4>Travel App</h4>
          <p>
            This project shows the front page of a marketing website meant for a
            specific business I'm interested in.
          </p>
        </li>
        <li class="portfolio-item">
          <img src="images/portfolio-4.png" alt="" class="portfolio-image" />
          <h4>Map of Favourite Spots</h4>
          <p>
            This project shows the front page of a marketing website meant for a
            specific business I'm interested in.
          </p>
        </li>
        <li class="portfolio-item">
          <img src="images/portfolio-5.png" alt="" class="portfolio-image" />
          <h4>Photo Gallery</h4>
          <p>
            This project shows the front page of a marketing website meant for a
            specific business I'm interested in.
          </p>
        </li>
        <li class="portfolio-item">
          <img src="images/portfolio-6.png" alt="" class="portfolio-image" />
          <h4>Calculator</h4>
          <p>
            This project shows the front page of a marketing website meant for a
            specific business I'm interested in.
          </p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```